# how to parse temperature data from Esxi server

Tags: vmware-esxi, monitoring, dell, snmp, ibm

I need to parse temperature data from esxi servers, to db for visualization the server room stats. I have 3 servers running esxi 6.5 
    IBM System x3250 M3
    IBM IBM System x3550 M4 Server
    Dell PowerEdge R630
I tried snmp walk but i cant find temperature data. I would be great to have data at least from one server

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Configuration" tab in vSphere Client, the first choice on the "Hardware" box is health status. That should give you all the information you need.

If the sensors are not showing anything, click the "Reset sensors" button in the top right corner. That solved the issues I was having with monitoring.

If noise is the issue, you may want to look into getting a better heatsink or quieter fans.

Edit: Also check out [this article](https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2009/03/monitoring-esx-hardware-with-powershell.html), which shows you how you can get CPU temperature data using powershell.

Comment: Its working there but, i need somehow parse it to query it to the db

Comment: The only method I found to parse that information is written in my answer under "Edit".

Comment: Yes did`t saw it at the start i think this might work for me, thank you. I will test it then  if everything is  worked i will accept your answer. Thanks a lot